# AWS CloudWatch interpreting insights graph -- how many read/write IOs will be billed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

### Introduction

We are trying to "measure" the cost of usage of a specific use case on one of our Aurora DBs that is not used very often (we use it for staging).

Yesterday at 18:18 hrs. UTC we issued some representative queries to it and today we were examining the resulting graphs via Amazon CloudWatch Insights.

Since we are being billed USD 0.22 per million read/write IOs, we need to know how many of those there were during our little experiment yesterday.

A complicating factor is that in the cost explorer it is not possible to group the final billed costs for read/write IOs per DB instance! Therefore, the only thing we can think of to estimate the cost is from the read/write volume IO graphs on CLoudwatch Insights.

So we went to the CloudWatch Insights and selected the graphs for read/write IOs. Then we selected the period of time in which we did our experiment. Finaly, we examined the graphs with different options: "Number" and "Lines".

### Graph with "number"

This shows us the picture below suggesting a total billable IO count of 266+510=776. Since we have choosen the "Sum" metric, this we assume would indicate a cost of about USD 0.00017 in total.

[image: number-ption]

### Graph with "lines"

However, if we choose the "Lines" option, then we see another picture, with 5 points on the line. The first and last around 500 (for read IOs) and the last one at approx. 750. Suggesting a total of 5000 read/write IOs.

[image: using "lines" option]

### Our question

We are not really sure which interpretation to go with and the difference is significant.

So our question is now: How much did our little experiment cost us and, equivalently, how to interpret these graphs?

## Edit:

Using 5 minute intervals (as suggested in the comments) we get (see below) a horizontal line with points at 255 (read IOs) for a whole hour around the time we did our experiment. But the experiment took less than 1 minute at 19:18 (UTC).

Wil the (read) billing be for 12 * 255 IOs or 255 ... (or something else altogether)?

[image: 5 min intervals]

Note: This question triggered another follow-up question created here: [AWS CloudWatch insights graph — read volume IOs are up much longer than actual reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367524/aws-cloudwatch-insights-graph-read-volume-ios-are-up-much-longer-than-actual-r)

Comment: Seems like the last image you used Average instead of Sum, would the Sum be different of just the same?

Comment: Also, it seems consistent to me, the groupings of 15 Minute would be around ( 500 + 750 + 750 + 500 ) = 2500. The 5 minutes groupings shows 12 * 250 which would be roughly 2500 also....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Aurora RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html)

VolumeReadIOPs

> The number of billed read I/O operations from a cluster volume within
> a 5-minute interval.
>
> Billed read operations are calculated at the cluster volume level,
> aggregated from all instances in the Aurora DB cluster, and then
> reported at 5-minute intervals. The value is calculated by taking the
> value of the Read operations metric over a 5-minute period. **You can
> determine the amount of billed read operations per second by taking
> the value of the Billed read operations metric and dividing by 300
> seconds**. For example, if the Billed read operations returns 13,686,
> then the billed read operations per second is 45 (13,686 / 300 =
> 45.62).
>
> You accrue billed read operations for queries that request database
> pages that aren't in the buffer cache and must be loaded from storage.
> You might see spikes in billed read operations as query results are
> read from storage and then loaded into the buffer cache.

Imagine AWS report these data **each 5 minutes**
[100,150,200,70,140,10]

And you used the Sum of 15 minutes statistic like what you had on the image

F̶i̶r̶s̶t̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶"̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶"̶ ̶v̶i̶s̶u̶a̶l̶i̶z̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶r̶e̶s̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶g̶g̶r̶e̶g̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶g̶r̶o̶u̶p̶.̶ ̶I̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶1̶5̶ ̶m̶i̶n̶u̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶g̶g̶r̶e̶g̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶(̶7̶0̶+̶1̶4̶0̶+̶1̶0̶)̶

Edit: First, the "number" visualization represent the whole selected duration, aggregated with would be the total of (100+150+200+70+140+10)

The "line" visualization will represent all the aggregated groups. which would in this case be 2 points (100+150+200) and (70+140+10)

It can be a little bit hard to understand at first if you are not used to data points and aggregations. So I suggest that you set your "line" chart to **Sum of 5 minutes** you will need to get value of each points and devide by 300 as suggested by the doc then sum them all

[Added images for easier visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk8I4.jpg)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The image shows two horizontal lines at 133 (write) and 255 (read) IOs between 18:50 and 19:50 hrs. (UTC). Suggesting 12 * (133+255) = 4656 billed IOs. But the actual experiment took less than 1 minute (!) at 19:18 hrs. (UTC). So why isn't there a single point around that time? Now it seems we are getting billed 12 times too much ... ?

Comment: When I set the aggregration period to 1 hour, the lines metric stays at 255 read IOs. But, according to your answer, it should aggreate the 12 points at 255 into a single point of 12*255. It does not do that. Could you elaborate a bit on that, please?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v49Iusj
Sorry I was mistaken. The "Number" aggregation seems to only care about the "Full time line" but not the "Aggregation period" specified in the "Graphed Metrics" tab
Hope this image can clear your doubts.
For the exact cost calculation, please refer to the doc. I did not understand the part about the multiplication to 12?

Comment: No worries, I added an image to pin point what I meant with the "12 times", related to the length of our experiment and the (read) IO volume that AWS indicates at a height of 255 during a whole hour ...

Comment: The SUM value of different time aggretations are consistent as I commented above. I have no idea why the read/write IO stay up the whole hour, that would call for another question ... To calculate the cost, follow the doc I quoted in the answer :D

Comment: Yes, created another question for that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367524/aws-cloudwatch-insights-graph-read-volume-ios-are-up-much-longer-than-actual-r) and accepted this one. Thanks.