# AWS CloudWatch insights graph — read volume IOs are up much longer than actual reading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

## Introduction

We were trying to "measure" the cost of usage of a specific use case on one of our Aurora DBs that was not used otherwise.

2020 Oct 8 between 19:18 and 19:19 hrs. UTC we issued some representative queries to it. This was 1 minute (!) of action.

Then, the next day, we went to the CloudWatch Insights and selected the graphs for read/write IOs for the day before like in the graph below:

[image]

## Observation

From the graph it is suggested that there was a constant read and write IO load between 18:50 and 19:50. However, our little experiment took place at 19:18 (yes, exactly at half time). Our experiment took only 1 minute, but the graph suggests a whole hour of activity.

## Questions

First, why is there not a single point at 19:20 hrs.? Instead, the line is up for a whole hour, exactly around the time our our action. Artefact?

Second, and more importantly, if that is an artefact, will we be billed for 12 times the read/write IOs or for only the 1 at 255?

Note: This question was spun off of this one: [AWS CloudWatch interpreting insights graph -- how many read/write IOs will be billed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282728/aws-cloudwatch-interpreting-insights-graph-how-many-read-write-ios-will-be-bi)

Comment: I am curious. Can you add the tag amazon-rds also?
I am sure that you will be billed for whole 12 data points but for why something is reading and writing to your DB, I can only guess that to be either AWS's reporting fault or maybe some kind of backup is running

Comment: Likely, we'll also approach customer support with this specific issue and we may be able to answer our own question here when they can explain it. Hope is still out that someone from the community could shed some light on this.